# Regex allowed typing confirmation

Tags: vb.net

Does below regex correct to examine whether `a-z A-Z spaces` are the only one allowed to type?

```
   Dim pattern As String = "^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"
    Dim r As New Regex(pattern)

    If Not r.IsMatch(TextBoxX1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("not allowed")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it does what you require, but that's a **really** unnecessary expression. Instead of checking if each character is A-Z, 0-9 or a space, look for anything ***that is not*** that.

```
Dim pattern As String = "[^A-Z0-9 ]"
Dim r As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If r.IsMatch(TextBoxX1.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid input!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End If
```

**Note:** By specifying `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` the match is *case-insensitive*, so even if I specified `A-Z` it will match `a-z` as well.

**Online test:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q23XiA

Pattern explanation:

```
[^              => Match any character that IS NOT...
    A-Z0-9      => ...A-Z, 0-9 or a space (there's a space on the end of that).
]               => End of character group.
```